# Decorator Which Returns a function and Accepts a Parameter

Tags: decorator, python-2.7

I'm not the best with decorators and I'm trying to build one for a task (obviously).  Basically I have my function which I wish to decorate (it's a Django app but it shouldn't matter)

```
def foo(request, param):
    # do something w/ param
```

Now I need to build a decorator to take in a parameter:

```
@mydecorator('VALUE')
def foo(request, param)
    pass
```

So basically I need my decorator to take in the value foo, do some work with request, then return

Here is what I have so far but it's not working  :(

```
def mydecorator(val):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something with request with respect to val
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Need help, thanks

Comment: the second code block is missing a ':' at the end. I cannot edit this as SO want at least 6 non-space characters in an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the second example definition for foo missing a ':' at the end, the main problem is that mydecorator should return a decorator as it is a function call.

If mydecorator would not take an argument you would write:

```
@mydecorator
    def foo(request, param)
        pass
```

and not

```
@mydecorator()
    def foo(request, param)
        pass
```

given that knowledge you should start with:

```
from functools import wraps

def mydecorator(val):
    def myrealdecorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # do something with request with respect to val
            print 'I know about', val
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return decorator
    return myrealdecorator

@mydecorator('VALUE')
def foo(request, param):
    print 'inside foo'

foo('arg1', 'arg2')
```